# Working but not studying with a student visa in Canada

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada, students, student-visa

I have a 4-year-long Canadian student visa (issued in August 2014). I have both a French and a Swiss passport and I used my Swiss passport when I applied for my student visa.

I love my life in Canada but don't quite like my studies and I might have an opportunity for an interesting job (in Canada). I know that with my student visa I am allowed to get a job. I don't think I am required to deliver any document to the Canadian government to prove that I am still studying (although the information will be clear on my tax declaration).

Can I freely drop my studies and stay in Canada to work until the end of my student visa? Does it appear like I am lying to the government? Can I get into trouble for that? Does it decrease my chances to later apply for another visa or for permanent residency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I freely drop my studies and stay in Canada to work until the end of my student visa?

No.

> Does it appear like I am lying to the government?

It doesn't *appear*. You **are**.

> Can I get into trouble for that?

Of course.

> Does it decrease my chances to later apply for another visa or for permanent residency?

Most definitely.

Comment: That's a clear-cut answer! I would have loved to have a piece of text supporting your claim but I suppose that the answer is obvious enough that one doesn't need that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot drop your studies as you want. Your college/university is always informing the Border Services if you are currently enrolled in a semester on regular intervals. The only rule I remember from my studies is that you can have a maximum of 4 months drop between two semesters. And you need to finish at least 2 semesters consecutively before taking that drop. If you take a drop more than that your college/university **WILL** inform the border services that you have come on a study visa but you aren't enrolled currently (which makes you technically an illegal immigrant).

On top of that while being enrolled in a full time program you aren't allowed to work for more than 20 hours (part-time) while your semester is currently going on. So if you're thinking of doing work-study together, there's a limitation on that too. Check your student permit. They clearly mention this in the bottom. This work permit is called Off Campus Work Permit (OCWP) I believe.

You might get into trouble if you decide to apply for a Permanent Residence in the future. First of all, all programs that offer permanent residence require you to have basic *legal work experience* and/or a college/university degree (which you were planning to skip).

See [here](http://www.canadavisa.com/news/entry/cic-proposes-changes-to-international-student-program-01022013.html) for more details.